# I want a bouncing ball on the wall in turtlegraphics, but they stop and they wander and send an error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i draw some triangles and they should bounce on the wall,but they don't bounce, they don't go straight, they print an error message after a few seconds.

When I let the triangles move only in the shape of a cross, the triangles faltered and an error message came out.

```
import turtle
import random
def draw_sq(t,distance=400):#Draw a box
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-200,200)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(distance)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(distance)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(distance)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(distance)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0,0)
    t.pendown()
def add_tri():
    global l_tri
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    t.shape("triangle")
    x=-200
    y=random.randint(-200,200)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.setheading(random.randint(-89,89))
    # make triangle and start
    l_tri.append(t)# add a triangle to list
def successMan():#write word succes 
    global playing
    if playing==True:
        t.write("success")

def turn_right():
    global right
    right = True

def turn_left():
    global left
    left = True

def turn_up():
    global up
    up = True

def turn_down():
    global down
    down = True

def _turn_right():
    global right
    right = False

def _turn_left():
    global left
    left = False

def _turn_up():
    global up
    up = False

def _turn_down():
    global down
    down = False

def is_touch(x,y,triangle,threshold=20):
    global playing
    if((x-triangle.position()[0])**2+(y-triangle.position()[1])**2<=threshold**2):
        playing=False#if triangle touches the turtle make playing False

def timer_go():
    global heading
    global l_tri
    global t
    global playing
    global up
    global left
    global down
    global right# heading is where turtle heads
    if up:
        if right:
            heading=45
        elif left:
            heading=135
        elif down:
            heading = heading
        else:
            heading=90
    if down:
        if right:
            heading=315
        elif left:
            heading=225
        elif up:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 270
    if left:
        if right:
            heading = heading
        elif up:
            pass
        elif down:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 180
    if right:
        if left:
            pass
        elif up:
            pass
        elif down:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 0

    t.setheading(heading)
    t.forward(10)
        # turtle controller
    for i in range(3):#triangles move
        if (l_tri[i].position()[0]<-200):
            l_tri[i].setheading(180-l_tri[i].heading())
            l_tri[i].forward(10)
        if (l_tri[i].position()[0]>200):
            l_tri[i].setheading(180-l_tri[i].heading())
            l_tri[i].forward(10)
        if (l_tri[i].position()[1]<-200):
            l_tri[i].setheading(-l_tri[i].heading())
            l_tri[i].forward(10)
        if (l_tri[i].position()[1]>200):
            l_tri[i].setheading(-l_tri[i].heading())
            l_tri[i].forward(10)#triangle bounces on the wall
        l_tri[i].forward(10)
        is_touch(t.position()[0],t.position()[1],l_tri[i],threshold=20)
    # check triangle and turtle
    if (playing==False):
        t.write("FAIL")
        #Fail

up = False
down = False
right = False
left = False
playing = True
heading = 0
l_tri = []

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
t.speed(0)
draw_sq(t)
screen = t.screen

screen.onkeypress(turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(turn_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(turn_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_down, 'Down')


for i in range(3):
    add_tri()
for i in range(1,200):
    time = i*100
    screen.ontimer(timer_go, time)
screen.ontimer(successMan,20000)
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

This should be a game where the player avoids triangles in the box.

Comment: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`  it means that inside some function you run this function `def fun(): fun()`. Try write code without recursion.

Comment: I understood.Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run it I see error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

but I don't see recursion in code.

Maybe problem is

```
for i in range(1,200):
    time = i*100
    screen.ontimer(timer_go, time)
```

Probably it creates too many functions.

You can run it once

```
screen.ontimer(timer_go, 100)
```

and use it again at the end of `timer_go()`

```
def timer_go():

    # ... rest of code ...

    screen.ontimer(timer_go, 100)
```

and it will repeat it all time.

You can see this method even in official documentatiton: [turtle.ontimer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @furas (+1) about how to set up your `ontimer(timer_go, 100)`, but I see other issues with your code.  I've reworked it below and I hope you find some of the changes useful.

Specific issues: you need to (re)read about `global` as half the time you're using it incorrectly; you don't need to reinvent `turtle.distance()` (e.g. in `is_touch()`); you need to separate `playing == False` from failure as you need to stop play on either success or failure;  You should only need to specify the number of triangles in one place:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

FONT = ('Arial', 16, 'normal')

def draw_square(turtle, distance=400):  # Draw a box
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-200, 200)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(distance)
        turtle.right(90)

def add_triangle():
    triangle = Turtle("triangle")
    triangle.penup()
    triangle.goto(choice([(choice([-150, 150]), randint(-150, 150)), (randint(-150, 150), choice([-150, 150]))]))
    triangle.setheading(randint(-89, 89))
    # make triangle and start
    triangles.append(triangle)  # add a triangle to list

def successMan():  # write word success
    global playing

    if playing:
        player.write("Success!", font=FONT)
        playing = False

def turn_right():
    global right
    right = True

def turn_left():
    global left
    left = True

def turn_up():
    global up
    up = True

def turn_down():
    global down
    down = True

def _turn_right():
    global right
    right = False

def _turn_left():
    global left
    left = False

def _turn_up():
    global up
    up = False

def _turn_down():
    global down
    down = False

def is_touch(player, triangle, threshold=20):
    return player.distance(triangle) < threshold

def timer_go():
    global playing

    heading = player.heading()

    if up:
        if right:
            heading = 45
        elif left:
            heading = 135
        elif down:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 90

    if down:
        if right:
            heading = 315
        elif left:
            heading = 225
        elif up:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 270

    if left:
        if right:
            pass
        elif up:
            pass
        elif down:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 180

    if right:
        if left:
            pass
        elif up:
            pass
        elif down:
            pass
        else:
            heading = 0

    player.setheading(heading)
    player.forward(10)

    # turtle controller
    for triangle in triangles:  # triangles move
        x, y = triangle.position()

        if not -200 < x < 200:
            triangle.setheading(180 - triangle.heading())
            triangle.forward(10)

        if  not -200 < y < 200:
            triangle.setheading(-triangle.heading())
            triangle.forward(10)

        triangle.forward(10)

        # check triangle and turtle
        if is_touch(player, triangle, threshold=20):
            playing = False
            player.write("FAIL!", font=FONT)  # Fail

    if playing:
        screen.ontimer(timer_go, 100)

up = False
down = False
right = False
left = False

playing = True
triangles = []

draw_square(Turtle(visible=False))

for _ in range(3):
    add_triangle()

player = Turtle('turtle')
player.speed('fastest')

screen = Screen()

screen.onkeypress(turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(turn_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(turn_down, 'Down')

screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeyrelease(_turn_down, 'Down')

screen.ontimer(successMan, 20_000)

timer_go()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

I suspect your `RecursionError` is due to your key events as your model seems to be that multiple keys can go down at a time.  But if a key is held too long, it can cause a key event inside a key event and this looks like recursion.  You can usually fix this by disabling the key event handler as the first thing inside the event hander, do your work, and then reenable the key event handler.

However, you may also have the OS-controlled automatic key repeat logic working against you.  If your key handling turns out to be a problem, consider using a simpler approach.